# Dynamic list, excel formula

Tags: excel

I'm going crazy over this, trying to figure out how to make a dynamic array to create a smaller list from a bigger list based on a criteria. All of it needs to be dynamic because the base list will change. Have googled for two days but can't find the proper solution.

I'm a rookie creating these things. Have tried below but it doesn't work:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('2.Data'!$L$3:$L$300;SMALL(IF('2.Data'!$L$3:$L$300="12378";ROW('2.Data'!$L$3:$L$300)-ROW('2.Data'!$L$3)+1);ROWS(B$2:B2)));"")
```

Example:

```
Column A
1. 12345
2. 12345
3. 12378
4. 12345
5. 12378
6. 12345

Column B (result)
1. 12378
2. 12378
```

`Column B` should have a fancy formula that gets value from `column A` based on criteria=ends with 78, presented without empty cells between values.

Comment: This kind of problem really begs a macro solution, not a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter the **array formula**:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$26,SMALL(IF(RIGHT($A$1:$A$26,2)="78",ROW($A$1:$A$26)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

*(your version of Excel may require the ; rather than the , in the formula)* and copy downward:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

You can avoid the array formulas if you use a "helper" column.

Comment: I came up with: =INDEX('2.Data'!$L$1:$L$100;LARGE(IF(RIGHT('2.Data'!$L$1:$L$100;2)="78";ROW('2.Data'!$L$1:$L$100);-1);ROW($B$1:$B$100)))

Comment: @jkpieterse  Looks good......I have spent so many, many hours helping users to "speed-up" their worksheets that I will almost always use a helper column rather than an array formula.

Comment: @Erik  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I totally agree. But I like a puzzle so a nice array formula challenge is like finishing the Times puzzle to me :-)